# Will a standard CMS on a shared web hosting account work for this?

Tags: cms, database, shared-hosting, dedicated-hosting

I have two questions concerning CMS's that I need answered if possible:

I need to create a site with a Database. This site will in due time have lots of traffic and many users if things go as planned. Is it better to have the CMS on a shared web hosting account or is it better to have a dedicated server for this?

The site I want to create needs to be able to create groups where each group has its own admin. The admin of the group decides the content that each member can view/access.

The information of one group can be shared to other groups as well. This means that only the information content is shared but not the group's member data.

Should I use a single or multiple databases for this problem?

Is this something that can be done using standard CMS systems out there. or should I try to build one myself?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have three parts here:

1. User and authorization management
2. Content classification, profiling and/or authorization (possibly done by "tagging" or metadata)
3. Content management--some CMS handle parts of the above 2

If this setup is core to your business model, consider developing your own setup, though most independent CMS professionals I've met have a background in another CMS and many avoid entering the market with another system.

If the content and groups simply support your main business, then consider a CMS and development platform that fits your skills, budget, and needs.

To really answer the database question it depends on how your groups (customers) will evolve. A single application with features for all suggests you can start with fewer environments, possibly hosted, and a single code base.

If each group gets their own set of content as well as features you need the ability to create and maintain the differences (or to creatively offer certain groups certain features).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like something you will have to create yourself. Most CMS will not fit your needs. As for many databases, you should be ok with just one although you will need many tables within the database.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have to ask whether to use a CMS or build a custom one makes me lean towards to 'just get one that suits you'. I can not give you any advice on that, you will need to do some research for that. Find similar sites and see how they work, what they use.
You start from scratch, try to make it the best start ;)

About the dedicated server: I suggest you don't. Just go for a common hosting company with some good settings, uptime and performance. You say that a lot of people are going to use your site, but they're not now! Begin small, small=cheaper. When you start growing, most hosting companies can grow with you.

I believe GoDaddy has some nice blades which can upscale with your wishes. They can start with a small blade and you can check what you need more (more memory, or maybe bigger disk, etc).

**I can promise you that when you need dedicated hosting, you know that you're gonna need dedicated hosting.**

Answer (score 0):

i believe "Elgg" is best suit for your needs. There you can create/manage groups.try their demo before use.

Every Shared Hosting have limits(resource usage).contact your provider about the limits before signup.i recommended to use "vps" is good option.